# Fixing broken namespaces in WSDL for wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

**Problem:** I am trying to create stubs using wsimport from a WSDL, while parsing i am getting the below warning :

> warning: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 's1:guid' to a(n) 'type
>   definition' component.

My namespaces definition looks like this :

```
<definitions xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/";
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/";
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/";
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
xmlns:s0="https://domain/Counter.asmx?WSDL";
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/";
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/";
targetNamespace="https://domain/Counter.asmx?WSDL
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/";>
```

when i look at the WSDL i have definitions like below :

```
  <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GetNewsAreaIDResult" type="s1:guid" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
```

I figured the namespace `http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/` is moved and unavailable, so how do i fix it ? can i create an xsd document just for the S1 definition and override the default definition in the WSDL during wsimport if yes will wsimport look for others like `xmlns:tm` in my custom xsd ?